Is there any fast way to solve this modular equation
I want to determine values of $n$ with $n^4\equiv1 \pmod {25}$, I just assume $n\equiv k \pmod {25}$ and take fourth power on both side for $k=1,..,24$. Is there any faster way?

It’s $25\mid n^4-1=(n^2+1)(n+1)(n-1)$

There are modular square root algorithms you can use for larger moduli, but for 25, your brute force method is probably as good as anything.

If you’re doing brute force you really need to check only $1$ through $12,$ since $(-1)^4=1$

@all thanks for this!

FWIW Calculating modular square roots modulo arbitrary composite integer n is not trivial, but is tractable if you can factorize n. I wrote a program to do it called modnsqrt.c here https://github.com/FastAsChuff/int128-functions-in-c.

Do you know Hensel’s lemma?

Since the multiplicative group of non-zero integers modulo $25$ is cyclic, once you have found $4$ solutions, you have found them all

By Hensel (cf. dupes) each root $,x ,\equiv, r \pmod{! 5}$ lifts to a root $$x ,\equiv, r-\dfrac{f(r)}{f'(r)},\equiv, r-\dfrac{r^4-1}{4:!\color{#c00}{r^3}\bmod 5},\equiv, \overbrace{r+(r^4-1)(r \bmod 5)}^{\large 1/\color{#c00}{r^3}\ ,\equiv,\  r\pmod{!5}}\pmod{!5^2}\qquad$$ so the notrivial root $,2,$ lifts to $,2+(2^4-1)(2)\equiv 7\pmod{!25},,$ therefore we conclude that the roots $,\pm1,\pm2\pmod{! 5},$ lift to $,\pm1,\pm7\pmod{!5^2}\ \ $

Generally the above shows that the roots of $,x^{p-1}-1\pmod{!p^2},$ are the $p$'th powers of the roots $!\bmod p,$ (put $,f'(r) \equiv -r^{-1}\pmod{!p}$ in Hensel's formula), e.g. here $,2\mapsto 2^5\equiv 7\pmod{!5^2}\ \  $

@BillDubuque:  doesn't it simply follow from Euler's theorem and the fact $\mathbb Z/p^2\mathbb Z$ is cyclic that $(x^{p})^{p-1}\equiv x^{\phi(p^2)}\equiv1\bmod p^2$?

@J.W.T Yes of course but that alone is not sufficient (it doesn't prove they are the only roots, i.e. that the roots lifts are unique).

@BillDubuque:  $1^p, 2^p, 3^p,…(p-1)^p$ are certainly distinct mod $p^2$ because they’re distinct mod $p$ (and of course I meant $(\mathbb Z/p^2\mathbb Z)^\times$ in my comment above, but it was too late to edit it)

for any $n$ not divisible by $5$   we find $n^4 \equiv 1 \pmod 5.$   Call it $x$   and say it is one of $-2,-1,1,2 \pmod {25}.$  Next, for mod $25$   we take $x + 5 y$  and see what happens.
$$   (x + 5y)^4 = x^4 + 20 x^3 y + 150 x^2 y^2 + 600 xy^3 + 625 y^4 $$
$$   (x + 5y)^4 \equiv x^4 + 20 x^3 y \pmod{25}$$
When $x = \pm 1$  we see that $x^4 \equiv 1 \pmod{25}$  and we must take $y \equiv 0 \pmod 5.$  Thus $x \equiv \pm 1 \pmod {25}$
When $x = \pm 2$  we see that $x^4 \equiv 16 \pmod{25}$  and we must have $20 x^3 y \equiv 10 \pmod {25},$  or $4 x^3 y \equiv 2 \pmod {5}.$
When $x=2$ we need $32y \equiv 2 \pmod 5 $  so $y \equiv 1 \pmod 5.$   Thus $x+5y \equiv 7 \pmod {25}.$ In ordinary integers, $7^4 = 2401$
The final value is $-7 \pmod {25}$
This business comes under the name Hensel. For a prime power, we keep raising the exponent of the prime.

Suppose $n^4\equiv1\pmod{25}$. Write $n=5a+b$ with $a,b\in\{0,1,2,3,4\}$. Then
$$1=n^4=(5a+b)^4\equiv20ab^3+b^4\pmod{25},$$
which shows that $b^4\equiv1\pmod{5}$ and so $b\neq0\pmod{5}$. Plugging in $b=1,2,3,4$ yields
\begin{eqnarray}
1&\equiv&20a\cdot1^3+1^4&\equiv&20a+1\hphantom{1}\pmod{25}\\
1&\equiv&20a\cdot2^3+2^4&\equiv&10a+16\pmod{25}\\
1&\equiv&20a\cdot3^3+3^4&\equiv&15a+6\hphantom{1}\pmod{25}\\
1&\equiv&20a\cdot4^3+4^4&\equiv&\hphantom{1}5a+6\hphantom{1}\pmod{25},
\end{eqnarray}
and solving for $a$ yields $a=0,1,3,4$ respectively. This leaves $n=1,7,18,24$ and a quick check shows that these all satisfy $n^4\equiv1\pmod{25}$.

I think you mean mod $25 $ where you typed mod $4$

@J.W.Tanner Indeed, thanks for catching that. Corrected now.

To sum up the comments, there are algorithms for calculating modular square roots, but your brute force method is probably expedient modulo $25$.
A couple of comments on the brute force method.  You really need to check only $1$ through $12$, since $(-1)^4=1$, so if $k$ is a solution, then so is $-k\equiv25-k$.
And since the multiplicative group of non-zero integers modulo $25 $ is cyclic, once you have found $4$ solutions, you have found them all.
A more direct solution method is to note that $25\mid n^4-1=(n^2+1)(n+1)(n-1)$.  Since $5$ dividing more than one of the factors would lead to a contradiction, we have $25\mid n^2+1$ or $n+1$ or $n-1$.
$25\mid n+1\iff n\equiv-1\equiv24\bmod25$.
$25\mid n-1\iff n\equiv 1\bmod25$.
$n^2+1\equiv0\bmod5$ means $n\equiv\pm2\bmod 5$.  $n^2+1\equiv0\bmod25 $ could then be solved using Hensel's lemma or simply noting that if $n\equiv2\bmod5$ then $n\equiv 2 $ or $7$ or $12$ or $17$ or $22$ mod $25$, and we see that $7^2+1\equiv0\bmod25.$
Besides $n\equiv7\bmod25$, a solution of $n^2+1\equiv0\bmod25$ is $n\equiv-7\equiv18\bmod25$
Addendum inspired by Bill Dubuque in comments:
For this particular problem, the solutions are $1^5=1$, $2^5=32\equiv7$, $3^5=243\equiv18$, and $4^5=1024\equiv24\bmod25$, since by Euler's theorem if $5\nmid a$ then $a^{\phi(25)}=(a^5)^4\equiv1\bmod25$.
